# How can I render the result of Html.Action() from within a custom helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Due to an implementation detail, I have what would be a partial view that needs to be a full-fledged view "rendered" using `<%= Html.Action(Model.ViewerToRender) %>`. It works fine in my dev spike where I can put that line directly on the page, but in the production code it **must** be in a ViewPage helper method that returns a void. Given the `htmlString` variable in the following code, how can I render it to the page from within this helper?

```
public static void RenderDocumentViewer(this ViewPage<DocumentViewModel> page)
{
    if(!page.Model.UseRenderPartial)
    {
        var htmlString = page.Html.Action(page.Model.ViewerToRender);
        // The following line is what I don't know how to do:
        page.RenderHtml(htmlString);
        return;
    }

    page.Html.RenderPartial(page.Model.ViewerToRender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
page.Response.Write(htmlString);
```

Comment: I came up with `page.Writer.Write(htmlString)`; but you beat me to it!

Comment: It might be worthwhile to do some reflectoring and find out which of those calls the other. Or perhaps they even manage to accomplish the same result in entirely different ways! Regardless, I see `Response.Write` a lot more, so I think it's probably best---or at least most idiomatic---practice.